# How to keep personal tab active while switching to other tabs in microsoft teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

We have embedded an external website as a personal tab in Microsoft Teams. We want to keep the tab active in the background even if the user switches away from the personal tab. How could we achieve this?

Comment: If you want to keep the tab active in backgroung.You can Pop out the tab.Like below-
[![enter image description here][1]][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyrZI.jpg

Comment: If you want to do it in programmatically, then Currently there is no way to keep the tab active in the background.

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT Why I want to keep the tab active is beacuse we have loaded an external website (which allows the user to make or recieve phone calls) as a personal tab in MS teams, So when the user is away from the tab and receives a incoming call, we want to notify the user about the incoming calls. Is there a way to do this apart from bot?

Comment: Hello @Brahmajith Pm, Currently there is no Programmatical way to do this.

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT Pop out of the tab option that you mentioned, can we do that with help of microsft sdk ?

Comment: Currently You cannot automate pop-out app. This is by design. Could you please Raise a user voice - https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472